# Почему метод класса не изменяет значение переменной?

Tags: python

Простой пример на питоне, который  поверг меня в ступор:

```
class A:
a = 0
def set_a(s):
    a = s
    print(a)
A.set_a(10) # 10
print(A.a)  # 0
```

Почему после присваивания переменной a в методе set_a значения 10, она всё равно равна 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
class A:
    a = 0 # статическая переменная класса A
    def set_a(s):
        a = s # локальная переменная функции set_a
```

Вы пытаетесь менять статическую переменную класса, ну так надо указывать её полное наименование всегда (кроме начальной инициализации сразу после `class`):

```py
class A:
    a = 0
    def set_a(s):
        A.a = s
        print(A.a)

A.set_a(10) # 10
print(A.a)  # 10
```

Везде кроме описания переменной непосредственно сразу в `class` нужно указывать её полное название (с классом впереди). Иначе вместо неё вы присваиваете значение новой локальной переменной. Просто сразу внутри класса это статическая переменная класса, а внутри метода класса - это уже локальная переменная этого метода.

P.S. Переменные **экземпляра** класса, которые через `self.` - это вообще другая история. Так тоже можно, конечно, но нужно понимать между ними разницу.

Comment: а зачем при присванивании ``A.a``? ``self.a`` же

Comment: @Эникейщик `self.a` - переменная объекта, `A.a` - переменная класса. Из вопроса следует, что автор хочет поменять классовую

Comment: а, точно . . . .

Answer (score 0):

```
class A:
    a = 0
    def set_a(s):
        a = s
        print(a) 
A.set_a(10) # 10
print(A.a)  # 0
```

`a` в `set_a` локальная переменная, `a` в классе он просто не видит и создает новую переменную

Чтобы обращаться к элементам класса, необходимо в параметрах класса указывать `self` первым параметром, а также обращаться к элементам класса с помощью `self.`. Методы без `self` в параметрах будут являться статическими, в подобных методах изменять значения переменных класса изменять нельзя, только при обращении к классу напрямую

Для хранения переменных класса необходимо объявить переменную этого класса

```
class A:
    a = 0
    def set_a(self,s):
        self.a = s
        print(self.a) 
a = A()
a.set_a(10) # 10
print(a.a)  # 10
```

Если вы хотите изменить переменные класса, то необходимо обращение к ним:

```
class A:
    a = 0
    def set_a(s):
        A.a = s
        print(A.a) 
A.set_a(10) # 10
print(A.a)  # 10
```

Comment: @Danis Ох, да, уже исправил, не сразу заметил, что он пытается в статическом методе изменить значение

Comment: Вы пока ещё не понимаете разницу между переменными класса и переменными **экземпляра** класса. И те и те можно менять. Разберитесь. )

Comment: Я не имею представления как при любом из двух вариантах инициализации переменных в классе можно в статическом классе их менять, если Вы знаете, то пожалуйста отправьте мне источник. В-принципе, плохо понял суть комментария, я пытался простым языком объяснить человеку принцип работы без лишней терминалогии

Comment: Ну, посмотрите мой ответ, например. Либо вы не понимаете разницу между 1) экземпляром класса и его переменными и 2) самим классом и его статическими переменными, либо просто везде в ответе опускаете слово "экземпляр". И так и так не очень хорошо. Нужно чётко понимать разницу.

Comment: Возможно, я понял, что Вы имеете ввиду. Но при прямом обращении к классу, если переменная класса не была объявлена, то она создаться. В любом случае, для общего развития обновлю ответ. В-принципе, мои слова почти являются реальностью